# Как сделать вывод нынешней даты в текстовом и числовом формате: June 28, 2022 на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать вывод нынешней даты в текстовом и числовом формате: June 28, 2022 на JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.info(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-us', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'}))
```